# Looping through a set of xpaths and checking the test values

Tags: loops, csv, xpath, jmeter, webdriver

I have around 100 xpaths which only differs only in index at the end.

The sample xpaths range from:

```
(//div[@class='something']
//div[@class='some other thing'])[1]
```

to:

```
(//div[@class='something']
//div[@class='some other thing'])[100]
```

And I have a CSV file with expected values in each of these fields.

Note that I am doing this in Webdriver sampler in JMeter, keeping language as javascript.

How do I loop through these xpaths, and get `text()` of these, and check if they are as per the expected values in the CSV file, using minimum code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to create a [for loop in JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)?

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  var xpath = "(//div[@class='something']//div[@class='some other thing'])[" + i + "]"
  var actualText = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath(xpath)).getText()
  var expectedText = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readLines(new java.io.File('/path/to/your/file.csv')).get(i-1)
  if (actualText != expectedText) {
      WDS.sampleResult.setFailure(true)
      WDS.sampleResult.setFailureMessage("Text mismatch")
  }
}
```

With regards to using JavaScript as the language the overall idea is not very great.

- It's recommended to use [Groovy language for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy), other options have performance and resource consumption problems
- Nashorn engine [has been removed from Java 15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372) so your solution will not work on newer JVMs